# cómo poner un echo dentro de otro con php

Tags: php

quiero imprimir en un echo una variable pero esta se encuentra dentro de otro echo y no se imprime nada. anteriormente cuando solo usaba el html sin el primer hecho si muestra la variable sin ningún problema

lo que quiero es imprimir en h1 la variable

```
***<h1 class="display-5 fw-bold"><?php echo $_SESSION["nombreV"]?></h1>***
```

---

```
echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
            <meta name="description" content="" />
            <meta name="author" content="" />
            <title>Usuarios Somnus</title>
            <!-- Favicon-->
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/conduit.ico" type="image/x-icon">
            <!-- Bootstrap icons-->
            
            <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
            <link href="dash2022/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1a0189f574.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- Responsive navbar-->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
                <div class="container px-lg-7">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#!">Somnus</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="cerrarsesion.php">Cerrar Sesión</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <!-- Header-->
            <header class="py-3">
                <div class="container px-lg-5">
                    <div class="p-4 p-lg-3 bg-light rounded-3 text-center">
                        <div class="m-4 m-lg-5">
                            <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold"><?php echo $_SESSION["nombreV"]?></h1>
                            <p class="fs-4"><?php echo $_SESSION["puestoV"] ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Las líneas:

```
<h1 class="display-5 fw-bold"><?php echo $_SESSION["nombreV"]?></h1>
                        <p class="fs-4"><?php echo $_SESSION["puestoV"] ?></p>
```

deberían quedar así:

```
<h1 class="display-5 fw-bold">' . $_SESSION["nombreV"] . '</h1>
                            <p class="fs-4">' . $_SESSION["puestoV"] . '</p>
```

Cuando haces el `echo` solamente necesitas concatenar tus variables.
Como sugerencia personal, en este caso, yo personalmente escribiría el `html` y le incrustaría el `php`.

PD: te faltaron un par de ";"